# OpenCV Returning error message when webcam is not connected

Tags: python, opencv

I am using OpenCV 3.3 with Python 2.7 on a Windows 10 PC. In one of my projects, I am connecting an external webcam to do some tracking. Everything works well as long as the webcam is connected. If the webcam is disconnected before the program runs/during the program, the program crashes. When I tried a dummy program to check what's going wrong, I noticed that the program crashes in the line where i call cv2.VideoCapture(0) itself.

*Code Snippet:*

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0) -- this line is in the main program and if camera is not connected, the program crashes at this point

--The below lines are inside a function and is called by the main program based on some other input

> r, a = cap.read()
>
> while not r:
>
> > print 'Reconnect Camera'
> >
> > r , a = cap.read()
>
> print 'All Okay!'

I put the while loop in there to prevent problems if the camera is disconnected after the cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0) but before cap.read() inside the function. This also does not do the work as 'r' value becomes true in the second iteration even after the camera disconnects. I have put a graph below to represent the behavior of 'r' with camera's connection.

[a -> Camera is disconnected and 'r' goes to false;b -> Camera is still disconnected but 'r' is true now;c-> Camera is re-connected and 'r' goes to false;d -> Camera is connected, 'r' goes back to true but](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzDYB.jpg)

I might be doing something wrong! How do I fix this?! Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 0):

first you need to have at least one camera pluged, without any camera the program have to fail.
cv2.VideoCapture(0) is looking for the first camera (number cero), so if you plug the camera out will return error.
how to fix: list cameras, set the one that´s not the webcam as default

Comment: Oh okay. But, is there a way to prevent python crashing and instead return a error message saying no camera has been connected? As the program crashes, I am unable to identify the error type to use it with try-except.

Comment: is kind of weird your project using CV without camera plugged... use an if, in case no camera plugged, so don´t do videoCapture (it´s like natural to expect an error if no camera available), else do videoCapture: camera working properly.

Comment: I am not trying to use it without the camera. I just want my program to tell the user that camera is not connected if program is run instead of crashing! I tried what you suggested and itt still doesn't fix the issue! Thank you though! On a closer look, I found that **cap.read()[0]** returns a _false_ when the camera is disconnected and goes back to _true_  when i call the function again (the camera is still disconnected!!!!!). When I re-connect the camera, it returns false once and then goes back to true again! :( I am not sure if this is a problem with camera handling by openCV or windows.

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36268054/opencv-python-videocapture-read-does-not-return-false-when-rtsp-connection-is?rq=1 seems an OpenCV issue.

Comment: Thanks Lucas! Looks like they too have not found the solution yet!

For now, once the return becomes false the first time, I display a message and exit the program with 'exit()'. The user has to start from the beginning. Figured this was better than letting windows freeze. 

It would be great if there is a way to keep the program waiting until the cam is reconnected. If the 'ret' in cap.read() works reliably, this would be easy.